# Actual values vs Preditec values plot

Tags: machine-learning, visualization, data-science-model, model-evaluations

I was working on a project and I got a 0.98 R^2 score on both the training and test data sets and 0.91 training mse and 1.02 test mse, But my Actual values vs Predicted values looks like this, I was wondering that if this is considered accepteable and if my model is preforming well. I have also added the residuals plot.Thanks in advance.

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

train_r2 = model.score(X_train, y_train)
y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
train_mse = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred)
test_r2 = model.score(X_test, y_test)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
test_mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)
print(f'Test R^2 score: {test_r2}, Test MSE : {test_mse}')
print(f'Training R^2 score: {train_r2}, Training MSE : {train_mse}')

predicted_values = model.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(y_test, predicted_values, color='green', alpha=0.4)
plt.xlabel("Actual Values")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Values")
plt.title("Actual vs. Predicted Values")
plt.show()

residuals = y_test - predicted_values

plt.scatter(y_test, residuals, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel("Actual Values")
plt.ylabel("Residuals")
plt.axhline(y=0, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.title("Residual Plot")
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m with you on your skepticism! How do you compute those $R^2$ scores? How do you plot your data?

Comment: model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

r2 = model.score(X_train, y_train)
y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred)
test_r2 = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print(f'Training R^2 score: {r2}, Training MSE : {mse}')

Comment: predicted_values = model.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(y_test, predicted_values, color='green', alpha=0.4)
plt.xlabel("Actual Values")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Values")
plt.title("Actual vs. Predicted Values")
plt.show() thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Could you please edit that into your original question as a code block with comments? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, and thank you

Comment: Does this give you a score of $0.98$ or a score of $98?$

Comment: 0.98 and training mse is 0.91 and test mse 1.02.  I edited

Comment: Your residuals quite clearly don’t have a variance around $1$. I’m not sure where you made the mistake, but there’s something wrong.

Comment: Got it,I'll try to do this again, Thank you for your time.